# How to create new frame and scale image with size frame is selected in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imageview, scale

I have a list of images like the one on the left with fixed size frames,when i select one of the images i want a frame like the selected image to appear on the dialog with a ratio, that is, when I select the image with a square frame, in that dialog I have a picture frame like the one selected with the ratio,conversely, when I select an image with a rectangular frame, the dialog must also have a rectangular frame:

[image]

My code as below:

```
    /**
     * 
     * @param size is size of frame is selected
     */
    public void scaleImage(Size size){
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mPreview.getLayoutParams();
        final double viewWidthToBitmapWidthRatio = (double)size.getWidth() / (double)mBitmap.getWidth();
        layoutParams.height = (int) (mBitmap.getHeight() * viewWidthToBitmapWidthRatio);
        mPreview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mBitmap);
        mPreview.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
    }
```

so can anyone help me to solve this problem: